# IPC array program

Tags: c, arrays, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to make 2 program using shared memory concept . One program is accepting an array of integers and other program is sorting the array . However i am not able to do it correctly and cant think what is wrong in my program . Kindly check it and tell me what i am doing wrong .

thanks

program to accept array

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct shared_use_st
{
    int n;
    int wby ;
    int array[100];
};

int main()
{
    int shmid,running,i ;
    running = 1;
    void * shared_memory = (void*)0;
    struct shared_use_st * shared_stuff ;

    shmid = shmget((key_t)12345,sizeof(struct shared_use_st) , 0666|(IPC_CREAT));
    shared_memory = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);

    if (shared_memory == (void *)-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "shmat failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Memory attached at %X\n", (int)shared_memory);

    shared_stuff = (struct shared_use_st *)shared_memory;

    printf("\nEnter the no of array : ");
    scanf("%d",&shared_stuff->n);

    while(running) // infinite loop
    {
        while(shared_stuff->wby==1)
        {
            printf("waiting for producer 2");
            sleep(4);
        }

        for(i=0;i<shared_stuff->n;i++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter the array : ");
            scanf("%d",&(shared_stuff->array[i]));
        }
        shared_stuff->wby = 1 ;

    } // while

    return 0;
}  // main
```

program to sort array -

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct shared_use_st
{
    int n;
    int wby  ;
    int array[100];
};

int main()
{
    int shmid,i,j,running = 1,temp ;
    void * shared_memory = (void*)0;
    struct shared_use_st * shared_stuff ;

    shmid = shmget((key_t)12345,sizeof(struct shared_use_st) , 0666|IPC_CREAT) ;

    shared_memory = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);

    if (shared_memory == (void *)-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "shmat failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Memory attached at %X\n", (int)shared_memory);

    shared_stuff = (struct shared_use_st *)shared_memory;

    while(running) // infinite loop
    { 
        if(shared_stuff->wby==1)
        {
            printf("\n sortinggaaa the array in ascending order");

            for(i=0;i<shared_stuff->n;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<((shared_stuff->n)-1);j++)
                {
                    if(shared_stuff->array[j]>shared_stuff->array[j+1])
                    {
                        temp = shared_stuff->array[j];
                        shared_stuff->array[j] = shared_stuff->array[j+1] ;
                        shared_stuff->array[j+1] = temp ;
                    }
                }
            }

            sleep(5);
            printf("Array is now sorted");

            shared_stuff->wby = 0;

        } //if

    } //while

    return 0;
} //main
```

Comment: What exactly you are not able to do? You can't run them? you get errors? etc?

Comment: What is producer? who initializes shared memory, what starts first - lots of unclear things

Comment: Instead of using polling flag and sleep which is ugly and I am sure problematic to make work correctly (if not saying "wrong"), it'd better if you take a look at standard producer-consumer template with semaphore and start from that